# Laravel Cashier discount for multiple subscriptions

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm implementing a subscription system using Laravel Cashier which will have the option of multiple subscriptions (multiple products) and I would like to offer a discount for multiple subscriptions. Something along the lines of 10% off for 2, 20% off for 4 etc.

I can add a coupon in Cashier which would potentially work but if for example someone subscribes to 4 products and receives the 20% discount and then cancels 2 of the products, I can't see a way to reduce the discount to 10%.

Is this possible? Any recommendations on how to achieve this?